# unsure of how to fix the syntax error in in my sql code

Tags: mysql, sql, jupyter-notebook, syntax-error

[picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVAV4.png)

I am super new to jupiter notebook and sql statements. I assumed this syntax error had something to do with a missing colon, but I tried that and am stuck with the same error. Any ideas on what is missing?

Comment: a copy/paste of the query you tried and the error message would be far more useful than an image

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

```
select *
from grades
where score between 70 and 90
```

Note the order of values when using `between` IS important, you MUST use the lower value first, followed by the higher value. This is because `between` is really just a syntax shortcut which is translated into `score >= 70 and score <= 90'. If you try the following, it will not return any rows:

```
-- this will fail as the boundary values are back-to-front
select *
from grades
where score between 90 and 70;

-- which is the same as:
select *
from grades
where score >= 70 and score <= 90;
```

Also note that `between` includes both boundary values (i.e. 70 is included and 90 is included).